# Is there any similar implementation of python sha1 in Java?

Tags: java, python, django, cryptography, sha1

In a spring project I am trying to implement the Django like encryption logic for authentication because it will share the cookie with another python project. The issue I am facing is i am trying to sign the value in java in the same way its done in python.

When I call

```
value= hashlib.sha1(b'hello').digest()
# output b'\xaa\xf4\xc6\x1d\xdc\xc5\xe8\xa2\xda\xbe\xde\x0f;H,\xd9\xae\xa9CM'

key = hashlib.sha1(b'hello').hexdigest()
# output aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d
```

The value returned by hexdigest is matching with java value but if i see in only digest method I can see semicolon as well and comma too.

I have written this logic in Java which is not the same value as python digest.

```
private static void getKey(String key) {
        try { 
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1"); 
  
            String result = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest("hello".getBytes("UTF-8")));
            System.err.println("result===>>>" + result);
            //the output is AAF4C61DDCC5E8A2DABEDE0F3B482CD9AEA9434D
        } 
  
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can get the same value in Java ?

Comment: They’re just different encodings, sha1 is the same everywhere. Worth noting that sha1 is not encryption, it is not signing and it is far from sufficient for passwords.

Comment: There are some bad designs from the old days of Java that will be around forever, so you have to learn to avoid them. **Never** use `String.getBytes()` and never use `new String(byte[])`. **Always** specify the charset for both operations. When I use UTF-8 I get the same  answer as python

Comment: After lot of debugging i found that in python digest returns non-ASCII values where as in java it does not contain any non ASCII values. Your suggestion is good to remember always @PresidentJamesK.Polk but it still it doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: You changed your question. The outputs are now identical, as the comment in your question shows. Both python and java return the *same* output, an array of 20 bytes.

Comment: Yep, other than the case issue of the hexadecimal representation (which can be avoided by directly comparing the binary value after decoding) there is not much of a question left...